# Global Workbook reference!

Tags: vba, excel-2007

I'm creating a rather large macro that takes at present 5 workbooks (which will probably increase over time) with multiple worksheets, and combines them into one workbook.

Now, I'd have thought the easiest way to do all the various tasks taht I have to do would be to declare a global reference to the workbook. But it just doesn't seem to work.

So, I have declared it as:

```
Public E1_workbook          As Workbook
```

And then when the macro is kicked off, it will instantiate it.

```
   Private Sub Begin()

      ...
      Set E1_workbook = Workbooks.Open(Filename:="Workbook name")

      ...
      'Do other stuff
      ...

      Whatever

      ...

      'Close workbooks and free up resources...

      ...

   End Sub
```

And then further down in a different subroutine, I try to use the workbook:

```
   private sub Whatever()

        E1_workbook.Worksheets("worksheet name").Select
```

However this will fail stating that "The select method of worksheet class failed"

Even though I can copy the exact line from the '`Whatever()`' sub above into the '`Begin()`' sub and it works happily.

Why?

TIA

(The names of the workbooks and worksheets have been changed to protect the innocent)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you are opening a couple of Workbooks before calling the Whatever function. You can only call the `Select` function on a **visible Sheet** in an **active Workbook**.

That means you need to add `E1_workbook.Activate` in front of `E1_workbook.Worksheets("worksheet name").Select` and if the sheet "worksheet name" is a hidden sheet you also need to make it visible by using `E1_workbook.Worksheets("worksheet name").Visible = xlSheetVisible` you can hide the sheet again by setting the value to `xlSheetHidden`

By the way I would suggest that you put all your Workbooks in a Collection or an Array and pass this array to the whatever function rather than using public globals. One way to do that would be:

```
Private Sub begin()
    Dim srcWorkbooks As Collection

    Set srcWorkbooks = New Collection
    srcWorkbooks.Add workbooks.Open("fileName1")
    srcWorkbooks.Add workbooks.Open("fileName2")

    whatever srcWorkbooks
End Sub

Private Sub whatever(srcWorkbooks As Collection)
    Dim srcWorkbook As Workbook

    For Each srcWorkbook In srcWorkbooks
        srcWorkbook.Activate
        srcWorkbook.Sheets(1).Select
    Next srcWorkbook

    closeWorkbooks srcWorkbooks
End Sub

Private Sub closeWorkbooks(srcWorkbooks As Collection)
    Dim i As Integer

    For i = srcWorkbooks.Count To 1 Step -1
        srcWorkbooks(i).Close
        srcWorkbooks.Remove i
    Next i

    Set srcWorkbooks = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks Marg for taking the time to respond - I've just found out I'm an idiot.  Should have Activated the workbook before I try to reference the worksheet. More coffee I think. Sorry for wasting your time!

Comment: Ohh, and nice idea about the collection - I'll use that. Ta :-D